# SO doesn't appear in my accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts

I contacted SO by email maybe 7-14 days ago but nothing has changed since then even when I followed up.

In my accounts, I don't see SO.  This has been like this since I joined the site.  How can I get this added to the tab so I don't have to always go to the url to access the site?

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm for those interested: [This appears to be your account on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2213669/dustin) Indeed, it shows the list of five accounts you have noted, but not your SO account. Even though that page *is* your Stack Overflow account page.

Comment: @AndrewBarber yes that is my account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue in our network aggregation system - your account should now be fixed.

Sorry for the delay!

Comment: That is great thanks!